# WebView - Как разделить элементы с одной страницы и вывести под своим дизайном

Tags: java, android, android-studio, клиент, android-webview

Всем привет. Решил попробовать в Android Studio сделать простой клиент для сайта N. Хотел бы узнать, как реализовать такое: Выводим в лаяут только текст и картинки которые нам нужны и вставляем их в свой дизайн, т.е. оформляем как хотим кнопки, дивы и так далее. Например, на странице имеется меню, но оно не нужно нам, как его не отображать и ссылки вписать в свое меню? Читал некоторые статьи тут, но именно такого не нашел. За ранее спасибо.

Comment: ссылка на статьи не добавилась.

Comment: ссылки справа на странице либо в тегах можно посмотреть

Comment: я имел ввиду ссылку в вопросе, вы пишите  Читал некоторые статьи "тут" , но  "тут" никуда не ведет

Comment: Посчитал их не нужными в моем вопросе, так как не содержат конкретного ответа

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Для начала необходимо получить исходный код страницы сайта N.

```
URLConnection i1 = new URL("Ссылка на твой сайт N").openConnection();
i1.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "MyBrowser/1.0");
StringBuilder i2 = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader i3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i1.getInputStream()));
while (true) {
    String i4 = i3.readLine();
    if (i4 != null) {
        i2.append(i4);
        i2.append(System.lineSeparator());
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
i3.close();
```

Пусть исходный код ненужного меню будет таким:

```
<div class="menu">
    <button>Первая кнопка</button>
    <button>Вторая кнопка</button>
    <button>Третья кнопка</button>
</div>
```

Тогда нам нужно из полученного исходного кода `StringBuilder i2` удалить его.

```
String[] i4 = "".toString().split(" <div class=\"menu\">" + System.lineSeparator() + 
    "       <button>Первая кнопка</button>" + System.lineSeparator() + 
    "       <button>Вторая кнопка</button>" + System.lineSeparator() + 
    "       <button>Третья кнопка</button>" + System.lineSeparator() + 
    "   </div>");
```

Затем устанавливаем исходный код для твоего `WebView`.

```
WebView i5 = new WebView(Main.this);
i5.loadData(i4[0] + i4[1], "text/html", null);
```

Comment: Для меня это самый удобный вариант.

Comment: получается кроме меню, можно и другие ненужные элементы удалять?

Comment: Да. Можете удалить и другие элементы таким же способом, только нужно знать их исходный код.

Comment: исходный код есть, способ довольно интересный)) Как попробую отпишушь) Спасибо!

Comment: Есть еще вариант поработать с библиотекой [jsoup](http://jsoup.org)